# Image not sitting correctly inside DIV (Exclusive to Firefox it seems)

Tags: css, html

http://jsfiddle.net/Bzpj4/

The above DIV illustrates the problem. An image of 120x120 is sitting inside a DIV, also of dimension 120x120 which is inside a larger DIV, also of height 120px. The larger DIV has a border outline that the image is pushing away. Why? I have no idea. It's a problem exclusive to Firefox because it looks fine (as expected) in other browsers.

Any help is appreciated.

(I opened an earlier question but was a while responding and the replies have died.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding `overflow:hidden;` to the CSS for your inner box will fix the problem.

Comment: Appreciate that. Probably the only thing I didn't try.